# Multiple timeseries zoo objects in one panel; blogdown serve_site() doesn't load plot

Tags: r, blogdown

I've several *zoo* objects generated through a loop. I'd like to plot all objects in one panel. I suppose it can be done by first merging zoo objects to a matrix-like zoo object and and supply `plot.type = "multiple"` and `screens = ncol(merged-zoo-object)` arguments in `plot.zoo()`, but I can't figure out how to merge.

```
library(zoo)
for (i in 1:3) {
value <- rnorm(n = 12, mean = i)
index <- seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 12)
ts <- zoo(x = value, order.by = index)
plot.zoo(ts)
}
```

#### UPDATE

I've managed to create the plot (answered) and I want to create a blogpost with [blogdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you had with **blogdown** is that you were using an absolute local path `/home/rsl/r-plots/sample.png`. In general, it is a bad idea to use absolute paths, since they are not portable. In this specific case, when you publish your post to a web server, the meaning of `/home/rsl/r-plots/sample.png` will change. It indicates the file `/home/rsl/r-plots/sample.png` under the *root directory* of your website. For example, if your website is `http://example.com`, the file path means `http://example.com/home/rsl/r-plots/sample.png`, which is definitely not what you actually mean. The web server knows nothing about your local files on your computer, and certainly cannot find any files on your local disk, so the plot won't load on the web page.

In short, remove this:

```
ggsave(filename = "sample.png", path = "~/r-plots")
```

When you author a document using **knitr**, or any packages based on **knitr**, such as **rmarkdown**, **bookdown**, and **blogdown**, there is [no need to manually save plots using `ggsave()` or R graphical devices](https://yihui.name/en/2012/06/enjoyable-reproducible-research/). R plots will be automatically save behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of works, but code could've been cleaner.

```
require(zoo)
require(ggfortify)

merged.zoo <- zoo()
for (i in 1:3) {
  value <- rnorm(n = 12, mean = i)
  index <- seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 12)
  ts <- zoo(x = value, order.by = index)
  merged.zoo <- merge.zoo(merged.zoo, ts)
}

autoplot.zoo(object = merged.zoo, geom = "line")
ggsave(filename = "sample.png", path = "~/r-plots")
```

[image]

I now create a new post with `blogdown::new_post(title = "title")` and add the below text in `*title.rmd` file which is created by `new_post` command.

```
---
title: title
author: ~
date: '2017-10-05'
slug: title
categories: []
tags: []
---

![I want to see this plot](/home/rsl/r-plots/sample.png)
```

I expect to see the plot in the post named *title* when `serve_site()` is executed followed by `build_site()` with default settings. But plot doesn't load.

Comment: Note that if screens has more than one level as it does here then the default for plot.type is multiple so that argument could be omitted.  alternately the screens argument could be omitted since "multiple" implies that the series are to be plotted separately.

Comment: Yes, only supplying `plot.type = "multiple"` works. `ggfortify::autoplot.zoo()`, too works. @yihui-xie I believe you could indicate what I'm doing wrong with blogdown.

Comment: You should probably merge this "answer" with your question, since you actual question was raised in this "answer" (why the plot does not load).